# Implementation of SQL's three-valued logic

Tags: sql, logic, three-valued-logic

Is there a module in any SQL implementation that checks satisfiability/validity of a formula in 3-valued logic? 
If so, is there an open-source one?
My purpose is to evaluate the performance of such a module (if exists) on the specific task of checking satisfiability/validity of formulas in 3-valued logic, and not for general query computations.

Comment: evaluate performance over `query execution plan` regardless of the logic what matters most are `indexes` and `appropriate query structure`

Comment: The thing is that I have my own 3-val logic solver, and would like to check whether it can improve db performance (that is, whether it performs better than current 3-val logic solvers inside db implementations).

Answer (score 0):

You could represent the problem using bit-vector logic. For instance, the [`QF_BV`](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/tactic/portfolio/smt_strategic_solver.cpp#L50) bit-vector logic of the [`z3`](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) SMT solver.

As an example: http://listedfor11o.blogspot.com/2013/03/multi-valued-logic-in-z3.html